# RGB to CMYK Conversion and Mask/Crop - Photoshop

Tags: image, printing, crop, photoshop, mask

This may sound like stupid question, but for me it's important.

I don't have much experience with using Photoshop, because Inkscape is perfect for my needs (web). Now I would need to create something and print it. I know that color mode for printing should be CMYK.

Because I am more familiar with Inkscape(that does not support CMYK), can I create PDF in that program and then import it into Photoshop and change color mode to CMYK. Is that valid? It shows that color mode is changed, but is that all? Because this is not for me and I just want to know if person that I wouk this for will not have any problems when it comes to printing. How can I make sure that conversion to CMYK was good?

One more question. In Inkscape I can not crop image, but I can mask or clip it. Basically, image still exist, but you see only portion of it. When it comes to printing will printer print full image or just that portion of it or I will need to crop image?

Comment: "How can I make sure that conversion to CMYK was good?" You will need the correct ICC profile (for printer as a minimum, but ideally you should also have one that comes from calibration for the monitor so it displays correctly). It's better to keep it as sRGB for the PDF and use a proper ICC for printer/raster it will be printed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most part, when you print an RGB file on your printer, the printer will convert it to CMYK. It's ability to do so "well" will depend on how accurate you need it to be & what color profile it is printing from (sRGB generally turns out better than say AdobeRGB).

The main reason for you to convert a file is so that you can make any fine tune adjustments to the image after the change. So you're not leaving it to the printer to decide and possibly mess up.

I'm not familiar with InkScape so don't know how it'll export said artwork. When you open it in Photoshop however, you will be able to see if it tacked it on there. Then you can crop if need be.

Hope that helps.